# Batch script erroring out with thumb.db not found error

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, batch-rename

I am using following code for deletion of older files

```
rem declaration des variables
set path=E:\somefiles
set delai_retention=15

rem Purge recursive des fichiers
%WINDIR%\system32\forfiles /p %path% /s /m * /d -%delai_retention% /c "cmd /c del  /q @path"
opsexit %errorlevel%

rem Purge recursive des dossiers vides
%WINDIR%\system32\forfiles /p %path% /d -%delai_retention% -c "cmd /c if @ISDIR==TRUE rmdir /S /Q @FILE"
opsexit %errorlevel%
```

But while running the code every time my script ends with the following error

> Could Not Find E:\somefiles\Thumbs.db

How to fix this error?

Comment: `@FILE` is just the filename. Use `@PATH` instead (like in your first `forfiles` command)

Comment: oh - and DO NOT use `path` as a variable name. It's a system variable that tells Windows where to find it's executables. Use another name (like `mypath`, `folder`, etc.)

Comment: Thanks I will try that and soon will update you if it works

Comment: Also for the same script if iam trying to set path to some

Comment: Remote machine value then unc path is not supported error how to give value of remote path inside set path =//machine/share and then remaining lines but it gives me unc path not supported

Comment: in Windows, a coorect UNC path looks like `\\machine\share`. But even that doesn't help if a command doesn't support UNC paths. Use `net use` to assign a virtual drive letter, which is treated like a physical drive. See `net use /?` for more info.

Comment: The `forfiles` command also returns hidden/system items, like Windows Explorer's `Thumbs.db` or `Desktop.ini` files, but the `del` command cannot find them unless you specify the respective attributes by the switch `/A:HS` (or simply `/A` to delete *all*). **Caution:** if a file has both hidden *and* system attributes set, `del /A:H` *or* `del /A:S` deletes it as one attribute matches!

Answer (score 0):

First, a hint, forfiles works without you need to go to the winsys32 folder; in fact, every .exe in winsys32 is available without that code. Code without that reduces the file lenght, that is good.
Either, some files needs supervision to being deleted. Use del /q /f /s, is more efficient.
Don't use "path" as a name, is a system variable, this will have conflict. And i think that cmd /c is useless.
I think so that is best use @path instead of @file in the other command.
These will be like that:

```
rem declaration des variables
set epath=E:\somefiles
set delai_retention=15

rem Purge recursive des fichiers
forfiles /p %epath% /s /m * /d -%delai_retention% /c "del /q /f /s @path"
opsexit %errorlevel%

rem Purge recursive des dossiers vides
forfiles /p %epath% /d -%delai_retention% -c "if @ISDIR==TRUE rmdir /S /Q @PATH"
opsexit %errorlevel%
```

You can also add a `>nul` if your problem is with the responses. Like that:

```
rem declaration des variables
set epath=E:\somefiles
set delai_retention=15

rem Purge recursive des fichiers
forfiles /p %epath% /s /m * /d -%delai_retention% /c "del /q /f /s @path 0^>nul 1^>nul 2^>nul"
opsexit %errorlevel%

rem Purge recursive des dossiers vides
forfiles /p %epath% /d -%delai_retention% -c "if @ISDIR==TRUE rmdir /S /Q @PATH 0^>nul 1^>nul 2^>nul"
opsexit %errorlevel%
```

Now even if have some problem in deleting the file, won't be show.
I hope I helped you.